# MySQL insert changing encoding

Tags: php, mysql, encoding

I have a query which is not inserting as I expected.

My database is setup as follows:

```
show variables like "character_set_database";

Variable_name   Value   
character_set_database  utf8

show variables like "collation_database";

Variable_name   Value   
collation_database  utf8_general_ci
```

and the table I'm using:

```
SHOW TABLE STATUS;

Name    Engine  Version     Row_format  Rows    Avg_row_length  Data_length     Max_data_length     Index_length    Data_free   Auto_increment  Create_time Update_time     Check_time  Collation   Checksum    Create_options  Comment     
users   MyISAM  10  Dynamic     21  93  1964    281474976710655     2048    0   NULL    2014-11-12 15:06:53     2014-11-12 15:09:16     NULL    utf8_general_ci     NULL
```

When I insert using php as follows:

```
INSERT INTO users (ID, USERNAME, IP) values ('19', 'krazy²', '147.xxx.xxx.xxx') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE IP = '147.xxx.xxx.xxx';
```

The username value gets stored like as

> krazyÂ²

I've tried escaping using mysqli_real_escape and it still stores the value like that. If I do a manual insert (console), the value gets stored correctly. I would like the value to be stored like it is

> krazy²

or with html entities so that a select can retrieve the values.

Maybe I'm missing out on some encoding stuff so please redirect me if so.

Thank you

Comment: maybe the client connection is still using an 8bit charset; try issuing a `SET NAMES utf8` query just before your INSERT statement; or, because you are using mysqli, execute a `mysqli_set_charset()`

Comment: That's a client-side issue, you won't fix it changing server settings. Assuming your PHP app uses UTF-8 (you don't say), look for the piece of code that establishes the connection to MySQL: you're most likely omitting the encoding parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally came to a solution:
changed mysql server's encoding to UTF8, so my "my.cnf" looks like this

```
[client]
default-character-set=utf8

[mysql]
default-character-set=utf8


[mysqld]
collation-server = utf8_unicode_ci
init-connect='SET NAMES utf8'
character-set-server = utf8
```

Thanks for all your help